# Bootstrap panels larger than content when combined with a floating div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experiencing weird behavior when trying to mix Bootstrap 3 panels with a floating div.

In this specific case, the floating div is a `btn-toolbar`.  The panel stretches to the cover the height of the toolbar on its left instead of adjusting its height to that of the content inside it.  Changing the height of the toolbar by adding or removing buttons changes the height of the panel. I believe they shouldn't have any effect on each other.

Bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/129573

Answer (score 1):

This line in bootstrap.min.css - line 7 is causing it.

```
.clearfix:after, .container:after, .container-fluid:after, .row:after, .form-horizontal .form-group:after, .btn-toolbar:after, .btn-group-vertical>.btn-group:after, .nav:after, .navbar:after, .navbar-header:after, .navbar-collapse:after, .pager:after, .panel-body:after, .modal-footer:after {
```

clear: both;
}

So perhaps create a css rule

```
.main .panel-body:before, .main .panel-body:after{clear:none}
```

See http://www.bootply.com/129617

Comment: I tried using this technique for my issue where the '.btn-toolbar' is inside '.panel-heading'. With '.btn-toolbar:after{clear:both}' the '.panel-heading' stretches. But with 'btn-toolbar:after{clear:none}' the contents overflow the '.panel-heading'